# How to take input as a single character in C?

Tags: c, char, scanf, stdio, conio

I am relatively new to programming and C language in general. I was trying to make a pretty simple project of a calculator. For that I needed to take input as a single character. I use the visual studio code IDE.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
char type;
float x,y;
int main(){
    printf("Please enter number 1: ");
    scanf("%f",&x);
    printf("Please enter number 2: ");
    scanf("%f",&y);
    printf("Please enter what do you want to do with the numbers, insert m for multiplication, insert d for division, insert a for addition and insert s for subtraction: ");
    scanf("%c",&type);

    if(type=='m'){
        printf("The result is: %f",x*y);
    }
    else if(type=='d'){
        printf("The result is: %f",x/y);
    }
    else if(type=='a'){
        printf("The result is: %f",x+y);
    }
    else if(type=='s'){
        printf("The result is: %f",x-y);
    }
    else{
        printf("Invalid Input");
    }
}
```

This is my code but when I run this, VS Code skips the scanf() function in the following line:
`scanf("%c",&type);`
It directly gives the output of 'Invalid Input'. Can someone please help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `scanf("%c",&type);` --> `scanf(" %c",&type);` to first consume the prior line's `'\n'`.

Comment: OT: Better make sure `y` is not `0` before dividing...

Comment: "VS Code skips the scanf() function in the following line: scanf("%c",&type);" --> No, it did not skip that line.  `scanf("%c",&type);` read the prior input's left-over `'\n'`.  Try `printf("Invalid Input %d\n, type");` instead.